# Add multi row result of a query as values to another query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem to solve, that requires me to select multiple values from two tables. From table B I need the values of 3 rows that reference to a key column from table A.

From what I found online I got the feeling, that this seems to come down to nested or recursive/hierarchial selects. But I can't figure out how to build the actual query with my different conditions between table A and B...

Given are tables like that:

```
Table A
ID | Val1 | Val2
----------------
01 | QWER | WERT
02 | ASDF | SDFG
...| ...  | ...

Table B
ID | Pos | ... | Val5
---------------------
01 | 001 | ... | X
01 | 002 | ... | Y
01 | 003 | ... | F
02 | 001 | ... | J
02 | 002 | ... | R
...| ... | ... | ...
```

Column ID is obviously the reference value between A and B.

I need to build a query like this:

```
ID | Val1 | Val2 | Val5 at B.Pos 001 | Val5 at B.Pos 002 | Val5 at B.Pos 003
```

I wasn't able to create a query as follows due to the multiple conditions between A and B and result in a "right bracket missing" error:

```
select 
  A.ID, 
  A.Val1,
  A.Val2,
  (select B.Val5 from B where B.ID = A.ID and B.Pos = 001),
  (select B.Val5 from B where B.ID = A.ID and B.Pos = 002),
  (select B.Val5 from B where B.ID = A.ID and B.Pos = 003)
from A
```

Is there a way to do this? It's a case I never encountered before, so I am lost...

Comment: Self joins, i.e A join B as b1 join B as b2 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.id, a.val1, a.val2,
       max(case when b.pos = 1 then b.val5 end) as bval1,
       max(case when b.pos = 2 then b.val5 end) as bval2,
       max(case when b.pos = 3 then b.val5 end) as bval3
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
group by a.id, a.val1, a.val2;
```

Comment: Awesome, that works like a charm. Guess I found another chapter to learn  in SQL